# jQuery switch between classes

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code which is suppose to switch between classes on click. The code works on the first click but once I click on the same element for the second time it never switches to the opposite class. What am I doing wrong?

```
// enable on click
$('.disabled').click(function(event)
{
     $(this).removeClass("disabled").addClass("enabled");
     $(this).html("enabled");
});


// disable on click 
$('.enabled').click(function(event)
{
     $(this).removeClass("enabled").addClass("disabled");
     $(this).html("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Your problem is the .disabled event has been attached to .disabled, 

If you are removing the class .disabled how could the even work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method if you want to define events for future elements. The [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method only attaches events to the current elements which match the selector

An alternative method:

```
// Select all elements which should be affected, attach a click function:
$(".enabled, .disabled").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("enabled disabled");     // Toggle class

    var isEnabled = $this.hasClass("enabled"); // Get toggle state
    if (isEnabled) {                           // Example
        $this.text("enabled");
    } else {
        $this.text("disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('.link').click(function(event)
{
    $(this).toggleClass('enabled').toggleClass('disabled')
});
```

make sure `.link` starts with either `.enabled` or `.disabled`

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to Lee Price's answer:

The actual problem of your code is that at creation time of the two click handlers, both ".enabled" and ".disabled" only exist for a limited number of elements. Once you change the class for one element, it belongs to a new class, but the click handler still only handles the old elements of this new class.

Take a look at .live() (or .on() for jQuery 1.7+) for the purpose of binding events to "future elements"

Comment: should you not just extends lees answer? as opposed to creating a new answer :) as they are related

Comment: you're right ... I was in the middle of writing the first repsonse to the question when stackoverflow introduced Lee's answer. I just forgot to cancel and move it to a comment :-)

Comment: well, people would down vote you, I wouldn't but others would lol so it's all up to you.

Comment: This answer explains why the current code is not working, which is more useful than a block of code without further explanation. Since Lee already posted the code, it's also OK to refer to that answer, instead of posting a similar code.